# Cloud formation to terraform conversion

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following piece of code to be converted from cloudformation to terraform:

**Cloudformation:**

```
lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmName: lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm
      AlarmDescription: Alarm if elapsed wall clock time is too high
      AlarmActions:
        - !ImportValue 
          'Fn::Sub': '${EnvName}CWNotificationTopicARN'
      Dimensions:
        - Name: FunctionName
          Value: !Sub '${lbdServicesBInfoFunctionName}-${EnvName}'**
      Namespace: AWS/Lambda
      MetricName: Duration
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: '1'
      Period: '300'
      Statistic: Sum
      Threshold: '30000'
      TreatMissingData: missing
```

**Terraform:**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm" {
  alarm_name                = "lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "1"
  metric_name               = "Duration"
  namespace                 = "AWS/Lambda"
  period                    = "300"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  threshold                 = "30000"
  alarm_description         = "Alarm if elapsed wall clock time is too high"
  treat_missing_data        = "missing"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

I am not sure how to convert AlarmActions and Dimensions from CF to TF. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the current TF code?

Comment: I haven't added AlarmActions and Dimensions in TF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very straightforward to convert those properties to Terraform. Here is an example:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm" {
  alarm_name                = "lbdServicesBInfoDurationAlarm"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "1"
  metric_name               = "Duration"
  namespace                 = "AWS/Lambda"
  period                    = "300"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  threshold                 = "30000"
  alarm_description         = "Alarm if elapsed wall clock time is too high"
  treat_missing_data        = "missing"
  alarm_actions             = ["${EnvName}CWNotificationTopicARN"]

  dimensions = {
      FunctionName = "${lbdServicesBInfoFunctionName}-${EnvName}"
  }
}
```